# How to ask QtCreator to use a custom build library on user path instead of using system library

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, qt-creator, qmake

My Ubuntu has *ffmpeg* library in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. I also rebuild *ffmpeg* from source and install it into my home directory.
In project file, I have added following lines:

```
TARGET = testFFmpeg
INCLUDEPATH += /home/kiet/ffmpeg/include
LIBS += -L/home/kiet/ffmpeg/lib/ -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale
```

I build my project successfully. But my binary file still links to *ffmpeg* in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
ldd testFFmpeg | grep libav

libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x00007f9085ce7000)
libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x00007f90858e9000)
libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 (0x00007f908567a000)
```

How can I ask `qmake` to find library in my folder first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I ask qmake to find library in my folder first ?

Operator `+=` adds the item to the end of the list, but you need to put it at the head of the list like this:

```
LIBS = stuff $$LIBS
```